# Custom Attribute not Working

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add few custom attribute to General Information in Magento > Catalog > Manage Category

But this not going to work. Please help me to find out here are my code below.

**modules/Wri_CustomCategoryAttribute.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wri_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Wri_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**community/Wri/CustomCategoryAttribute/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Wri_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Wri_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Wri_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**community/Wri/CustomCategoryAttribute/sql/add_category_attribute/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php**

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'h2_text', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'H2 Text',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'view_more_text', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'View More Text',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));


$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'view_more_link', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'View More Links',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

I am following instructions from [here](https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
 $installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_mysql4_setup', 'core_setup');

    $installer->startSetup();

   $installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'h2_text', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'H2 Text',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'view_more_text', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'View More Text',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));


$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'view_more_link', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'View More Links',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));
```

Then add those attributes to attribute_set:

```
$setId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_category')->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

$attributesCodes = ['h2_text', 'view_more_text', 'view_more_link'];


foreach ($attributesCodes as $attrCode) {
        $installer->addAttributeToGroup('catalog_category', $setId, 'General Information', $attrCode);
    }
}

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Where I have to this section "Then add those attributes to attribute_set:"

Comment: In the same installer file :)

Comment: You can also try to change your:
`<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>`
To: 
`<class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>`
So you don't have to use  $installer = `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/eav_mysql4_setup', 'core_setup');` and you can use just `$this`

Comment: There is a chance that your installer worked, but it didn't create attribute_set link, so you have to check in `eav_attribute` table if attributes appeared, look for your codes in attribute_code column. Write down id's for those rows. Add new records to eav_entity_attribute table with your new attribute_id's and default (or your custom) attribute_set_id and correct entity_type_id.

Comment: Thanks @dudzio but still not working

Comment: I dont get any thing in my eav_aatribute table

Comment: Ok, try deleting your module row in `core_resource` table. As long as your module is in that table, the installer won't work (becouse it worked for the first time, but not as you expected).

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $attribute  = array(
            'group'                     => 'General',
            'input'                     => 'textarea',
            'type'                      => 'text',
            'label'                     => 'H2 Text',
            'global'                    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible'                   => 1,
            'required'                  => 0,
            'visible_on_front'          => 0,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front'  => 0,
            'is_configurable'           => 0,
            'searchable'                => 0,
            'filterable'                => 0,
            'comparable'                => 0,
            'unique'                    => false,
            'user_defined'              => false,
            'is_user_defined'           => false,
            'used_in_product_listing'   => true
    );

    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'h2_text', $attribute);
$attribute  = array(
        'group'                     => 'General',
        'input'                     => 'textarea',
        'type'                      => 'text',
        'label'                     => 'View More Text',
        'global'                    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'                   => 1,
        'required'                  => 0,
        'visible_on_front'          => 0,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front'  => 0,
        'is_configurable'           => 0,
        'searchable'                => 0,
        'filterable'                => 0,
        'comparable'                => 0,
        'unique'                    => false,
        'user_defined'              => false,
        'is_user_defined'           => false,
        'used_in_product_listing'   => true
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'view_more_trext',      $attribute);
   $attribute  = array(
        'group'                     => 'General',
        'input'                     => 'textarea',
        'type'                      => 'text',
        'label'                     => 'View More Links',
        'global'                    => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'                   => 1,
        'required'                  => 0,
        'visible_on_front'          => 0,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front'  => 0,
        'is_configurable'           => 0,
        'searchable'                => 0,
        'filterable'                => 0,
        'comparable'                => 0,
        'unique'                    => false,
        'user_defined'              => false,
        'is_user_defined'           => false,
        'used_in_product_listing'   => true
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'view_more_links', $attribute);
    $installer->endSetup();?>
```